# Xcode: How to upload a "new binary" to App Store Connect?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

So I'm submitting my app to the app store and got this error in an email **ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement**.
I've added that to XCode, but how do I upload a new binary to App Store Connect?
I don't even know what a 'new binary' is.

Comment: It just means, press `Product` -> `Archive` again, and reupload.

Comment: Gotcha, so achive and then `Distribute App` again? Awesome! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: As @aheze has said you just need to do the upload process again. Note: Don't forget to increment the build number!

Comment: @Owen26 How do you mean 'increment the build number'? After hitting achieve I just see `creation date` and `version: 1.0(1)`

Comment: @LovelyAndy the build number is the `(1)`. You can change that inside your project settings, in the "Build" text field. This can be automated with https://crunchybagel.com/auto-incrementing-build-numbers-in-xcode/